# Is there any possibility to assign an alias to all columns of a table at once?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

As mentioned above, I am trying to assign an alias to all columns of a table at once as there is an obvious problem in PDO if a column name is used in more than one table.

If I'm trying this SQL statement:

```
SELECT t12.*,t1.*,t2.* FROM `tableone2tabletwo` t12 
         LEFT JOIN tableone t1 ON t12.idone=t1.id
         LEFT JOIN tabletwo t2 ON t12.idtwo=t2.id
```

I'll receive an array like this with`$stmt->fetch()`:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [0] => 1
    [idone] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [idtwo] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
    [name] => Test2TwoText
    [4] => Test1Text
    [5] => 2
    [6] => Test2TwoText
)
```

As you see, the field gets overwritten(the last time by the last element with this name... ;-)), even though the table has an alias.

`fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` as Andrii Filenko recommended returns this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [idone] => 1
    [idtwo] => 2
    [name] => Test2TwoText
)
```

So here the data is even lost, not only just available via the numeric indices.

`fetch(PDO::FETCH_NAMED)` as Nigel Ren recommended returns this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )
    [idone] => 1
    [idtwo] => 2
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test1Text
            [1] => Test2TwoText
        )
)
```

Is there a simple and stylish solution for this problem or will I have to do this one by one?

(My DB is available at [DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/92ET4ANWxRuXkhkGJKxvRA/0) if you want to take a look!)

Comment: Try to use ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) instead of ->fetch()

Comment: @AndriiFilenko I tried it. See the result above!

Comment: You could try `PDO::FETCH_NAMED`

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks, that's a lot better than anything else before, even though it's still not the perfect solution.